# How to place files on a web server?

Tags: java, jquery, ruby-on-rails, webserver, jcrop

I'm new to web development, so sorry if this is very basic. I'm trying to install jCrop, an it says I need to "Place the files on your web server so you can request them from your page." How exactly do I do this? I've tried researching this but I can't find an explanation anywhere. I'm using Rails 4.0.10, if that helps.

Comment: You add them to the server your site is hosted on. The location will depend on what web server software you're actually using.

Comment: Are you really a ruby developer?

Comment: How is this related to Java? JRuby?

Comment: @D-side I thought the answer would be dependent on the language of my project, and I heard somewhere that jQuery was built using Java.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If it is javascript files put it in `app/assets/javascripts` directory in your rails project.
In `application.js` write `//= require_tree .`

More info you can get here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html

Comment: So if I have `//= require_tree .` already in my application.js, I should be good?

Comment: if you place your js files in `javascripts` folder - yes.  JS files will be loaded.

Comment: Same with css files and `stylesheets` folder.

Answer (score -1):

It depends.

A working solution would be to put it into `public` subfolder of your project that is intended for storage of static files. A Rails app responds to URIs that either hit a static file or an app route. Be careful and don't cause collisions between routes, otherwise parts of your app might become inaccessible.

An ideal solution though would be thorough integration into asset pipeline so that jCrop is only loaded in controllers that need it and no extra URIs are occupied. Always search if someone has already done this first, Rails community is **huge** and has done a lot of things. A search for gems [reveals `jcrop-rails-v2`](https://github.com/maxd/jcrop-rails-v2/blob/master/README.md). Could be a nice choice.

Comment: A silent downvoter could at least explain what's wrong. This is correct information relevant to the question. We can't get better answers just by downvoting those we don't like for some reason.